# C++ program fails to produce output when redirecting stdout to a file on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, bash, io-redirection

I'm trying to run the simple c++ program below on a computer cluster (running Linux, CentOS 6).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("/dev/stdout");
    file << "Hello, world\n";
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile (using `g++ test.cpp`) and run the program on the head node it works as I would expect whether I let the output go to the terminal of redirect it to a file.  That is,

```
$ ./a.out > myfile.txt
```

produces a file `myfile.txt` that contains the line "Hello, world" (I'm using bash).  If I run it on any of the execution nodes and let the output go to the terminal it works just fine; however, if I try to redirect the output to a file the file is always empty.

I'm aware that this isn't the "standard" way one would write a hello world program in C++.  I am actually having difficulties with a 3rd party program that attempts to write binary data to standard output using a library that requires a file name.  In trying to reduce the code to post, I found that the above is the simplest code that reproduces the problem I'm seeing in the bigger program.

I'm not an experience C++ programmer, so have no idea if the above example should or shouldn't work, but the fact that it works on some computers as I would expect but not others has me stumped.  I am also not sure whether this is something to do with the C++ code, bash or the system configuration.  The people I've asked about this already seem to be equally confused and have not been able to even suggest where to start looking.

I've created simple hello world programs in other languages, and these all work as expected on the execution nodes, so I assume that this is something specific to C++.

Can anyone explain to me, or help me identify why I'm observing different behaviour on machines running the same OS (and that are supposed to be configured the same), and is there a (preferred) way in C++ to get library functions that require a file name to write to stdout?

Comment: Why are you trying to write to stdin, rather than stdout?

Comment: Assuming you used `stdout` and it actually does work on the head node - the problem may well be your cluster doesn't have a cluster safe `stdout`; what kind of cluster is it?

Comment: @Keshlam Smells like an X and Y problem.

Comment: yes, sorry that's a typo it should of cause be stdout not stdin.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry for my naivety, but I don't fully understand what you mean by cluster type.  Currently, I'm just ssh'ing into the execution nodes and running the program.

Comment: @jjellis From [here](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Suite_Overview/s1-clstr-basics-CSO.html), there are four major types of clusters - storage, high availability, load balancing and high performance.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks.  It's a high performance cluster.

Comment: @jjellis I don't think you can do direct node invocation on the nodes with your naive approach; you'll have to go through the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I looked around and found what may or may not be the program you are using: [uuencode](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/uuencode.htm). If thats not it, disregard this whole answer. That program looks tricky to use, so I will outline what I think is a sane way of using it:

Give anything as the "output file name" to uuencode

```
uuencode mybinaryfile anything > mytextfile
```

Then transfer the resulting "mytextfile" to a new system where you run

```
uudecode mytextfile -o mynewbinaryfile
```

Which produces "mynewbinaryfile". Again, the design of this program (especially the argument that I passed in as "anything") is not great, and there are concerns of endianness and type sizes when moving binary files from one machine to another which this program ignores. I recommend moving away from it.

As to the explanation, uudecode was trying to write to /dev/stdout, and on clusters and HPC machines, all the usual accomodations like /dev/stdout are no longer what they seem.

Comment: The program I'm actually trying to use is called [laser](http://code.google.com/p/clever-sv/), which in turn is using [bamtools](https://github.com/pezmaster31/bamtools) to write binary files.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "the usual accommodations like /dev/stdout are no longer what they seem"?

Comment: Since the stdout from several compute nodes must be multiplexed to a single output stream in many cases, the system handling output can be specialized. What is the result of `file /dev/stdout` run on the compute node ?

Comment: ``/dev/stdout: symbolic link to `/proc/self/fd/'``

Answer (score 0):

Well, likely the problem is with `mode` parameter for `fstream.open()`.

And, by the way it's a rather strange way to perform configure output...